# Can't show image and textblock inside a GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

This is my simple code to do this:

```
 <Grid>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="c:\myimage.jpg" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Image Name"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

But except the empty header, nothing shows up.
This is my first time using `GridView`. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListView` has no items, the `CellTemplate` is applied to each item in the list and if there are no items nothing will be shown. Did you perhaps mean to change the `Header` instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not binding a source then it is not going to generate any rows.  Show your XAML or code behind for binding a source.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use CellTemplate.  Here is an intro-level example of ListView: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1